# Hot to display binary image from db to image box.?8

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, binary

I want display student information and student image on my web page while selecting student Id from drop down list. Given below code is used for displaying information and image. But the image is not showing properly. Please check the code and out put screen.

Code:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        DataSet1TableAdapters.TextBoxTableTableAdapter tx;
        tx = new DataSet1TableAdapters.TextBoxTableTableAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = tx.GetstudData(int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue));

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = (row["FirstName"].ToString());
            TextBox2.Text = (row["SecondName"].ToString());
            byte[] barrImg = (byte[])row["StudImage"];
            string base6=Convert.ToBase64String(barrImg);
            Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base6," + base6;
        }
}
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT FirstName, SecondName, StudentImage FROM TextBoxTable WHERE (Id = @Id)
```

Aspx Source:

```
<div>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Data base:

[image]

OutPut:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

base64 instead of base6 ???

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base6;
```